# Can't find syntax issue causing 'KeyError' with number formatting.

Tags: python-3.x

I am working through a piece of code that says this is supposed to work in Python 3:

```
"{0:.{?}f}".format(t, precision).center(width)
```

Where:
  t is a float,
  width is integer,
  precision is integer

I keep getting this error message:

> return "{0:.{?}f}".format(t, precision).center(width)
>   KeyError: '?'

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where did you get that question mark?

Comment: The only way you could use `?` as an identifier is by making it a key in a dict and then using the dict-unpacking operator, `**`, to pass it to `format` as a keyword argument. For example, `"{0:.{?}f}".format(123.456, **{'?':7}).center(20)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
"{0:.{?}f}".format(t, precision).center(width)
```

Try:

```
"{0:.{1}f}".format(t, precision).center(width)
```

Just change that `?` to a `1`, because what is inside of the inner braces is used as a key or index.

## (Simplified) example

`.center()` will just create some padding to both sides, I ignored it here.

```
"{0:.{1}f}".format(14.6, 10)
# Outputs: '14.6000000000'

#Be careful with floating point, though
"{0:.{1}f}".format(14.6, 50)
#'14.59999999999999964472863211994990706443786621093750'
```